# Securing django on production

Tags: python, django, encryption, security

What are the common steps taken to secure a django app instance in production.
I am using sqlite so encrypting the database would be nice too.

And since the database is encrypted the app code should also be either encrypted or compiled only. Is it safe to simply delete all the *py files and leave the *pyc files?

Also, is it possible to disable the django shell (./manage.py shell) in the production server? Once the shell is accessible so is all the data.

The stack that I am using is: Nginx + Gunicorn + Django + SQLite all hosted on a rackspace dedicated server with a dedicated firewall.

**Basically, the objective is, that anyone with root access may not access the database contents.**

Comment: I'll never understand why people ask this. Who's got the ability to log into your server that shoudln't? What would "disabling the Django shell" even mean?

Comment: If someone has root access, the game is over and you've lost.

Comment: @FredLarson: Doesn't the hosting company have root access? Ergo, every single site hosted by a hosting company has root access to your production server.

Comment: @Ramin: If you can't trust your hosting company, find a different hosting company or host it yourself.

Comment: I'm voting to close, because this is a nonsense question.

Comment: I don't think it's a nonsense question. Security works in layers. Yes, if somebody has root, it is game over, but even then there are things you can do to limit or at least delay the damage.

Answer (score 4):

Securing django is an important question, but I think you are confused.

First of all even if you could make your code less easy to examine, it would not make it more secure. Secondly, it is possible to recover all but comments from pyc files.

Lastly, the django shell is a convenience for interacting with your application at the commandline. If anyone unauthorised were in a position to run it, it would not matter if you had disabled it - your security would already be completely compromised.

I strongly recommend that you do not administer your own production server with your current state of knowledge. Use a shared host, and follow your hosting service's security guidelines. Concentrate on the actual web security aspects of your application.

One more thing: you're not using the built-in server in production are you?

**Update**: You can't protect yourself from root, and even if you could, they could, say, just put the hard disk in another computer.

Comment: The hard disk is encrypted. =P

Comment: @Ramin If it's encrypted, such that physical access won't help an attacker, then the computer can't read anything from it. If the computer can read it, then anyone with physical access and root can also get the key.